# Dynamically hide / show the next list item. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im dynamically populating a UL list. This could contain 1 up to 5 items

I want to be able to show the first list item, and then on a click of a button in that list item hide it and show the next.

I have this so far -

HTML Structure

```
<ul class="grid">
   <li class="object">
     List Item 1
     <a class="show-next">Show the next list item</a>
   <li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$('.grid .object').hide().filter(':lt(1)').show();
$('.show-next').click(function(){
    $(".grid").find(".object").hide().next().show();
});
```

This code unfortunately is showing all the list items in the UL instead of just the next one.

Anyone give me a hand?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display/hide sub list items in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398298/display-hide-sub-list-items-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
.removeClass(active);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: how does it not answer the question? If added to his script function it will hide the li when you opens the next.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code so that you add an `active` class to the active element, because right now `$(".grid").find(".object")` is finding all the `li` objects in your `ul`, hiding them, looking for the next sibling for every element, and then showing those elements ... that's going to show every element in the list.  With an `active` class added to the currently active button, that would prevent your query from finding all the `li` elements in the `ul`.

So for instance:

```
$('.show-next').click(function(ev){
    $(".grid").find(".object.active").hide().next().show().addClass("active");
    $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Hi Jason - thanks for your answer - Im probably going to use this method, however the removeClass isn't removing the class. I do have the anchor now within a couple of div's inside the list item. Is this making it hard to find the parent?

Answer (score 0):

How's this: https://jsfiddle.net/fznk3ube/2/ I have updated the code and I believe it now includes all the functionality you asked for.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.object').hide();

    var clickListArray = $('.object').toArray();

    $(clickListArray[0]).show();



    $('.show-next').on("click", function () {
        var thisParent = $(this).parent();
        var nextInList = $(thisParent).next();
        $(thisParent).hide();
        $(nextInList).show();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The closing tag for your `li` is missing the backslash, e.g. `</li>` instead of `<li>`.

Apart from that, try this:

```
$('.grid .object').hide().filter(':lt(1)').show();

$('.show-next').click(function(){
    $(".grid").find(".object").hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();
    return false;
});
```

I have put together an example fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/utvgLqp6/

Please note that there's no sanity checking to see if it's the last item in the list or not.

Also, if you want to use this on dynamically created elements, you will need to do

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-next', function() {
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

First of all your are not closing each list item with `</li>`. You can take help of `parent()` to find the parent of the clicked element & then, can hide it & can show the next list item using `next()`

```js
$('.grid .object').hide().filter(':lt(1)').show();
$('.show-next').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide().next().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="grid">
   <li class="object">
     List Item 1
     <a class="show-next">Show the next list item</a>
   </li>
     <li class="object">
     List Item 2
     <a class="show-next">Show the next list item</a>
   </li>
     <li class="object">
     List Item 3
     <a class="show-next">Show the next list item</a>
   </li>
     <li class="object">
     List Item 4
     <a class="show-next">Show the next list item</a>
   </li>
     <li class="object">
     List Item 5
     <a class="show-next">Show the next list item</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code.

```
<ul class="grid">
   <li class="object">
     List Item 1<a class="show-next"> Show the next list item</a>
   </li>
        <li class="object">
     List Item 2
     <a class="show-next">Show the next list item</a>
   </li>
        <li class="object">
     List Item 3
     <a class="show-next">Show the next list item</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Below is the script you should insert.

```
$('.grid .object').hide().filter(':lt(1)').show();
$('.show-next').click(function(){
   $eL = $('.grid .object').filter(":visible");
  //  $(".grid").find(".object").hide().next().show();
    if($eL.next().length>0){
              $eL.next().show();
          }else{
               $('.grid .object')[0].show();
          }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ocpjcxL/)